# Android: image saved using copyPixelsFromBuffer is distorted

Tags: java, android, save, jpeg, bytebuffer

I am trying to make an image processing program in Android Studio and I have a problem concerning how to save a Bitmap.

My problem is about saving an image which comes from a ByteBuffer.

To show it here, I have done this: I load an image in a ByteBuffer and I try to save it, rescaled to 1014x1163 pixels. And the image I get is distorted, messy.

For example, here is an image I load:

[image]

And here is what I get in the image I save:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
imageSize = (int) (bmWidth*bmHeight*4);
ByteBuffer pixelsArray = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(imageSize);
ByteBuffer outputArray = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(imageSize);

workingBitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(pixelsArray);
workingBitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(outputArray);

int thiswidth   = workingBitmap.getWidth();
int thisheight  = workingBitmap.getHeight();

Bitmap copiedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(workingBitmap, Width, Height, false);

int thiswidth2   = copiedBitmap.getWidth();
int thisheight2  = copiedBitmap.getHeight();

outputArray.rewind();
copiedBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(outputArray);
SaveJPG(copiedBitmap);
```

The function SaveJPG works fine because if I call SaveJPG(workingBitmap) it saves a normal image.

Here is the code with variables values during debugging:

[image]

I am wondering if the problem comes from the fact that the output resolution is not a multiple of 4. That's mandatory in my program: the output image resolution can be of any value (odd or even).

I have tried many different things (copying workingBitmap and resizing the copy for example).

No success. I don't know what the cause of the problem is.

Does anyone have some source code which can save an image of any resolution, stored in a ByteBuffer ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even if `SaveJPG` works fine for one image this doesn't mean it is working properly with all images.

Comment: If the image is stored in a byte buffer then just save the contents of that buffer to disk.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(yourFileName)) {
    yourBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
    // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Or use this

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), yourbitmap,
    "File name", "description of the image");
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had already tried to save in PNG : same problem. I have tried your solution of using MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage but it does not work: same problem (the saved image is distorted too).

Comment: then the issue is with the bitmap. let me check your code again

Comment: what are loading the image from? `URI` or `URL` or anything else?

Comment: I am loading an image from 2 different sources: from the gallery or from the phone's camera. I have the same problem with both sources.

Comment: if you are loading from gallery, it is already saved. Why again?

Comment: And it will be better if you share the entire class's code

Comment: that will help the community understand it better

Comment: because I want to do some image processing between the loading and the saving. But for now I can load and display the image, but I am having problems with saving.

Comment: why don't you get the bitmap this way ? -> `Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);`

Comment: In the end, I need to save a Bitmap which will have been processed. So it can't be an URI.

Comment: The entire class' code is very long so it's easier to have only the interesting portion which is about saving.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause of the problem. It was simply due to a problem in the width and height of the input image: I was using the width and height of the View which displays the input bitmap, instead of using the bitmap's width and height.